# How do i use Django session to read/set cookies?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the Django sessions to read and set my cookies, but when i do the following the program just does not respond!

**sessionID = request.session["userid"]**

The program does not pass this point!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

First, Django already creates a user object for you so you don't need to store it in the session.  Just access it as:

```
request.user
```

For example, to get the username you would use:

```
request.user.username
```

Next, if you want to store information in the session you don't need to worry about it at the cookie level.  Simply write key / value pairs to the `request.session` dictionary.

[Here are some examples](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#examples) from the Django documentation.

**Edit**: The reason your program isn't responding is because a KeyError exception is being raised. 'userid' doesn't exist as a key in the session dictionary (unless you have added it yourself).

This is why it is better to program dictionary reads like this:

```
id = request.session.get('somekey', False)
```

Which will return False if 'somekey' doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Comment: Your code is wrong. request.session['somekey', False] simply tries ('somekey', False) tuple as a key. It should be get(key, default).